# How do I pass a folder-path, which may or may not have spaces in it, to a batch file and append it the PATH environment variable?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, command-prompt

**Explanation**

I have a simple little `.bat` file that looks like this. I'd like to run it anywhere from Windows 7 to 10. It doesn't do much just now but I'll later expand it.

```
#REM first argument includes path to folder which contains pdflatex.exe
set PATH=%PATH%;%1
where pdflatex #allows me to see if it can see the exe
```

The problem arises when I need to send a path that has spaces in it.

- If I pass a folder path with no spaces, and no quotemarks it works fine.
- If I pass a folder path with no spaces, and quotemarks it doesn't work.
- If I pass a folder with spaces, quotemarks or not, it doesn't work.

I believe this is because Windows does not work well with quotemarks in the PATH variable, what with it being semi-colon delimited. `%1` still contains the quotemarks by the time we're in the `.bat` file.

However quotemarks seem necessary from the command line perspective, to ensure it's treated as one argument.

The only method I can think of around this is to always include quotemarks around the path (ensuring it's always treated as one argument) and then cut off the first and last character.

This doesn't seem like an elegant solution, though, and I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

**In Short**

How do I remove the quotemarks from a batch file's arguments?

Comment: The `~` operator removes surrounding quotes if present, e.g. `set "PATH=%PATH%;%~1"`.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you.